# How to filter cases that have missing values in a variable designated by an external variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I actually have a solution to this problem, but I don't understand why it works, or why the "obvious" solution doesn't work.
Here's some fake data. I want to select the cases with valid values in column a, then b, then c.

```
foo <- data.frame(
    a = c(letters[1:5], rep(NA, 10)),
    b = c(rep(NA, 5), letters[6:10], rep(NA, 5)),
    c = c(rep(NA, 10), letters[11:15])
    )
```

Here is the resulting data frame:

```
> foo
      a    b    c
1     a <NA> <NA>
2     b <NA> <NA>
3     c <NA> <NA>
4     d <NA> <NA>
5     e <NA> <NA>
6  <NA>    f <NA>
7  <NA>    g <NA>
8  <NA>    h <NA>
9  <NA>    i <NA>
10 <NA>    j <NA>
11 <NA> <NA>    k
12 <NA> <NA>    l
13 <NA> <NA>    m
14 <NA> <NA>    n
15 <NA> <NA>    o
```

This is the code I wrote to filter out NA one column at a time:

```
myletters <- c("a", "b", "c")

for(the.letter in myletters) {

    foo2 <- foo %>%
##    this doesn't work. Why?
##    filter(!is.na(the.letter))
##    THIS ONE WORKS!
      drop_na(all_of(the.letter))
##    this works, too, but you can't run through all the letters
##    filter(!is.na(c))

    print(foo2)
    }
```

The third time through the `for` loop it produces this:

```
     print(foo2)
     a    b c
1 <NA> <NA> k
2 <NA> <NA> l
3 <NA> <NA> m
4 <NA> <NA> n
5 <NA> <NA> o
```

which is what I want. To me, the most obvious solution would be the `filter(!is.na(the.letter))` but I couldn't get that to work at all. It doesn't `filter` at all. I can hard-code the letter (as in the last line, `filter(!is.na(c))` ) but in some cases I have many, many variable to filter with.

Can someone tell me why the code that works, does, and why my obvious code doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code using `drop_na` works as `all_of()` takes a vector of column names as character strings, whereas in `filter` the character string is not treated as a column name. In that case you have to use the `.data` pronoun, i.e. try `filter(!is.na(.data[[the.letter]]))`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

for (the.letter in myletters) {
  foo2 <- foo %>%
    filter(!is.na(.data[[the.letter]]))
  print(foo2)
}
#>   a    b    c
#> 1 a <NA> <NA>
#> 2 b <NA> <NA>
#> 3 c <NA> <NA>
#> 4 d <NA> <NA>
#> 5 e <NA> <NA>
#>      a b    c
#> 1 <NA> f <NA>
#> 2 <NA> g <NA>
#> 3 <NA> h <NA>
#> 4 <NA> i <NA>
#> 5 <NA> j <NA>
#>      a    b c
#> 1 <NA> <NA> k
#> 2 <NA> <NA> l
#> 3 <NA> <NA> m
#> 4 <NA> <NA> n
#> 5 <NA> <NA> o
```